# How to test too fast AJAX response with Webdriver.io?

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm writing `Cucumber.js` tests with `Webdriver.io`. So far so good, but having an issue with too fast AJAX responses from the mock server. I'm never able to see "Loading..." as it's too fast, already loaded. My first fix was to put a 500ms latency into the mock server but I'm not sure thats the most cultured way... Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You should feel proud about your site's performance. ;-)

Comment: How about throttling your network speed. You can try it out on chrome with the F12 > network if it makes any difference.

Comment: I'd like to find a solution that is independent of my local/current environment.

Comment: @DavidR He said it's a mock server.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation and waitUntil with a callback function asserting desired state helped. Its documented [here](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one: waitForTextExample.js

http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html

```
<div id="elem" style="visibility: hidden;">Hello World!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('elem').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

and:

```
it('should detect when element has text', function () {
    elem = browser.element('#elem');
    elem.waitForVisible(3000)
});
```

Comment: I want to cover the initial case where the text is "Loading ..." which will be replaced with some content once the request has finished. The issue is the response is too fast, I can't see the "Loading ...", I can't check if thats there or not ...